# Mysql privileges on certain commands

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a stored procedure on my db.
When I try to execute the creation script I get an 
`1044 - Access denied for user 'cocpit_si_dbo'@'%' to database 'OTEST'`
I am sure that my script Is ok bc i execute it on my local machine and It runs just fine.

### My question Is can you disable the execution of certain commands ?

On the same machine I Can create drop alter tables BUT I cannot create a procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need create sp privilege. Have a look into [Stored Routines and MySQL Privileges](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/stored-routines-privileges.html)

Comment: don't worry about it, you are right i am missing the create routine and alter routine privileges . Thank you :)